# control tor via perl script

Tags: configuration

I installed `tor` on a ubuntu-server with the command

```
sudo apt-get install tor
```

and I also installed socks:

```
sudo cpan LWP::Protocol::socks
```

After this i wrote a perl script to read websites using the tor network, which works very well (simplified example):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new('agent' => 'any user agent string'},
);
$ua->proxy([qw/ http https /] => 'socks://localhost:9050'); # Tor proxy
$ua->cookie_jar({});
my $response = $ua->get('http://www.example.com/');
print $response->content;
```

As said before, this works very well, but there are some servers who block some tor exit nodes. Instead of sending the expected content with http-status `200 (ok)` they send the status `403 (forbidden)`. But some minutes later the same server sends `200 (ok)` together with the expected content, so I'm pretty sure that the problem are exit nodes who's IP addresses are blacklisted.

I know, that `tor` itself changes the route (and so the exit node) as far as I know every 10 minutes. But in the case, that a server sends `403` because it has made bad experiences with the concrete exit node that I'm using in this moment, I don't want to wait 10 minutes to get another exit node that hopefully is not blocked.

I want to change my perl script into something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new('agent' => 'any user agent string'},
);
$ua->proxy([qw/ http https /] => 'socks://localhost:9050'); # Tor proxy
$ua->cookie_jar({});


my $code = 403;
my $content = '';
while ($code > 399) {
    my $response = $ua->get('http://www.example.com/');
    $code = $response->code();
    if ($code > 399) {
        #####################################
        #  TELL TOR TO USE A NEW EXIT NODE  #
        #####################################
    } else {
        $content = $response->content;
    }
}
print $content;
```

Note, that this example is simplified: Not all http-status above 400 are usefull to change the route, and there are also some other reasons, that make it necessary to tell `tor` to use a new exit node.

My question is:

a) How can a perl script tell `tor` to change its route?
b) What other possibilities are there to control `tor` from a perl script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After crawling through manny different documentations I found a solution:

```
if (my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
            'PeerHost' => '127.0.0.1',
            'PeerPort' => '9051',
            'Proto'    => 'tcp')) {
    my @requ = ('authenticate ""','SIGNAL NEWNYM','QUIT');
    foreach my $requ (@requ) {
        print $socket $requ."\n";
        my $dummy = <$socket>;
    }
    $socket->close();
    print "OK: New circuit established\n";
} else {
    print "ERROR: couldn't connect with socket\n";
}
```

Explanation:

```
my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
            'PeerHost' => '127.0.0.1',
            'PeerPort' => '9051',
            'Proto'    => 'tcp')
```

creates a new socket object. If this did work, it returns the socket, otherwise *undef*.

I embedded this statement in an *if*-Statement. Its first block will be executed if the socket could be created, the second block prints an error message.

In the *if*-Block, I send this three commants through the socket to TOR:

1. authenticate ""
2. SIGNAL NEWNYM
3. QUIT

1 performs the null-authentification
2 does what I really want: This command tells TOR to establish a new circuit.
3 quits the conversation

At the end I close the socket and print a message.

I don't analyze TOR's response, but I have to read it (with `$dummy = <$socket>;`). One could check, if TOR really answers three times with "250", and react if not. But I decided to hope, that it always works.

Answer (score 2):

In response to part a) of your question, you can send Tor a SIGHUP. This won't kill the process, merely cause it to reload its configuration file, and create a new circuit.

In your script you could either use `kill` (using `system()`, etc.), in which case you'd need to know the pid of the Tor process you're controlling, or `pkill`, though in the case of the latter, you'd have no way of distinguishing between different Tor processes (if you were running more than one).

`kill -SIGHUP <pid_of_tor>`

Or:

`pkill -SIGHUP tor`

This assumes you're on a Linux box. I believe OS X has the similar `-HUP` signal, and I imagine Windows does too. Check the `man` page for more signals that can be handled by the process.

With regards to part b) of your question, I don't have any Perl-specific suggestions. If you're open to other scripting languages, have a look at [Stem](https://stem.torproject.org/) - a fully featured Python API - or one of the other controller libraries listed on [Stem's FAQ page](https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#are-there-any-other-controller-libraries).

**Edit**

The following short script has been tested and works with the desired effect of killing an already-running Tor process:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

system('pkill -SIGHUP tor')
```

**Edit #2**

It's likely that the script won't work as desired in the OP's case (see comments below). However, the answer may be of use to others with slightly different requirements.

Comment: Yes, tor and my script are running under linux (Ubuntu is a well known linux distribution). To "kill" tor sounds strange, but I'll try it. Too bad that there is no perl module to control tor. But on the FAQ page I did read, that there seems to be also a way to directly interact with Tor's controller interface.

Comment: `kill` is just the command you use to deliver a signal to a process. If you don't specify which signal, it delivers a SIGTERM by default, which _will_ terminate the process (hence the scary name). Language choice is always a controversial subject, so I'm not going to tell you not to use Perl (and I'm sure it still has valid use cases) :) What I will say is that everything I used to do in Perl, I now do in Python.

Comment: Sorry, this solution does not work. I can execute the system call `pkill -SIGHUP tor` from my perl script, but TOR still keeps using the old circuit. This command only works when I stop my perl script, send this command from command line, and then restart my script.

Comment: It works for me. I've edited my answer to include a very short script that kills the Tor process which is already running on my system. Are you sure your script is executing the `system()` call? i.e. Is it falling into the correct path? Have you written your script as a different user that doesn't have permission to kill the process? Are there any warnings being output by the script?

Comment: I used backticks instead of "system", but this does exactly the same. I wrote the script as root and I am running my script as root. No, there are no warnings. With your mini-script (with backticks instead of `system`) I also can manage, that tor uses a different circuit AFTER the script has ENDED. But it keeps using the old circuit WHILE the perl script is running (which means: while I have a living socks connection to TOR). See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256934/new-identity-for-tor-using-perl-on-linux

Comment: Ah, I think you're right about the socks connection - that's annoying. If you really want to use the control protocol and send a NEWNYM signal, have a look at how Stem creates a [connection](https://gitweb.torproject.org/stem.git/tree/stem/connection.py) to Tor's control port. It's in Python, but you should be able to do something similar using Perl's `IO::Socket` module. (I _think_.)

Comment: Either that, or you could try telneting to the control port using the `Net::Telnet` module, and [issuing the appropriate commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274462/result-identity-changing). (I've never used this module.)

Answer (score 1):

One-liner without modules:

```
`(echo authenticate \\"\\"; echo SIGNAL NEWNYM; echo QUIT) | nc localhost 9051`;
```